# SigningCertificateFile.pfx needed?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Is the .pfx file needed? I have done other implementations in Python where you do not need this file. Just the .cer file. Can you give some insights as to what this file does/is used for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .pfx file contain both the certificates public and private key where the .cer file only contain the public key. The public key is used to validate a SAML authn response in a relying party. The private key is needed to sign a request. According to the SAML 2.0 standard a relying party is required to sign SAML logout requests.

Furthermore, the project include an identity provider sample which signs the SAML authn response an therefore also needs a private key. A relying party use the corresponding public key to verify the signature.

Comment: okay that makes sense!  I should have clarified that I used a public key and private files so this makes sense